# How can I create a zip file without including the files parent directory (windows)?

Tags: windows, file, zip, command, roku

I want to create a zip file that doesn't include the parent directory, only the contents but I can't seem to figure out how. Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just select the files and create a zip archive with the name of the parent folder. When you unzip it will be extracted to the folder (zip file name).

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming since you have the [roku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roku) tag that you're asking because you want to build a Roku application zip file.

I would highly suggest using the [roku-deploy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/roku-deploy) npm package. It allows you to specify the list of files (in glob format) that you want to include in the zip.

Assuming your subdirectory contains all of the roku app files, and it's called "./rokuApp".

```js
//zip.js
const rokuDeploy = require('roku-deploy');
rokuDeploy.prepublishToStaging({
    rootDir: "./rokuApp",
    files: [
        "source/**/*",
        "components/**/*",
        "images/**/*",
        "manifest"
    ],
}).then(function(){
    return rokuDeploy.zipPackage({
        outFile: 'rokuApp.zip'
    });
}).then(function(){
    //the files have been zipped
    console.log('Success!');
}, function(error) {
    //it failed
    console.error(error);
});
```

Then you can build your zip like this (assuming you have Node.js installed):

```
node zip.js
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell.
Compress a directory that excludes the root directory

```
Compress-Archive -Path C:\Reference\* -DestinationPath C:\Archives\Draft.zip
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.3#example-4-compress-a-directory-that-excludes-the-root-directory

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Winrar software on your machine.

Answer (score -1):

select the files that you need to compress > right click > compress if you are using winrar